# Find all tables containing stringA, excluding tables having columns with a name like stringB

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find all tables with a name like %ABC% but excluding table_name:s that have any column with a name like %USER%

I try to join dba_tables with dba_tab_columns as

```
SELECT DT.OWNER, DT.TABLE_NAME
  FROM DBA_TABLES DT
       INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS DTC
          ON DT.TABLE_NAME = DTC.TABLE_NAME AND DT.OWNER = DTC.OWNER
 WHERE DT.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%ABC%'
```

In case the table has a column like %USER% the table_name should not be returned at all, so adding

```
AND DTC.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%USER%'
```

isn't good as it will only filter away the column %USER% not the whole table

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `join` for this, because the table name is in the columns table.  Just an aggregation

```
SELECT DTC.OWNER, DTC.TABLE_NAME
FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS DTC
WHERE DTC.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%ABC%'
GROUP BY DTC.OWNER, DTC.TABLE_NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DTC.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%USER%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

If you want to use two tables, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DT.OWNER, DT.TABLE_NAME
FROM DBA_TABLES DT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS DTC
                  WHERE DT.TABLE_NAME = DTC.TABLE_NAME AND
                        DT.OWNER = DTC.OWNER AND
                        DTC.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%USER%'
                 ) AND
      DT.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%ABC%';
```

Comment: Small note: I would use DBA_ALL_TABLES to search across really ALL tables. DBA_TABLES does not include object tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an "exists" clause

```
SELECT DT.OWNER, DT.TABLE_NAME
FROM DBA_TABLES DT
WHERE DT.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%ABC%'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'y' FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS DTC 
               where DT.TABLE_NAME = DTC.TABLE_NAME 
               and DT.OWNER = DTC.OWNER
               and DTC.COLUMN_NAME like '%USER%')
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, worked, gave the cigar to Gordon Linoff who was a couple minutes faster, apologies

Comment: haha no problem. Gordon types faster than me apparently. Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Remember that some objects (tables, columns) may have names defined in double-quotes; those will be missed by conditions comparing to all-caps strings. Just keep that in mind if it is important in your problem.

```
select dt.owner, dt.table_name
from   dba_tables dt
where  dt.table_name like '%ABC%'
  and  (dt.owner, dt.table_name) not in 
       ( select owner, table_name
         from   dba_tab_columns
         where  column_name like '%USER%'
       )
;

OWNER   TABLE_NAME
------  ------------------
SYSTEM  LOGMNR_TABCOMPART$
XDB     XDB$XTABCOLS
SYS     TABCOMPART$
SYS     LOGMNRG_TABCOMPART$
```